# Simple if statement configuration Help/SectionPageAdapter displaying info

Tags: java, android, loops, object, if-statement

Ok, so in part of the program that I am constructing, there is an Activity that receives and displays ListFragments in a ListView. This Activity also has a ViewPager (that allows for swiping) that Overrides SectionPageAdapter's getItem method in order to return the different fragments that ultimately make up the 5 different swipe-able sections in the Activity.

I am relatively new to programming in general and I am trying to think of a design that consists of only 1 Activity, and 2 fragments (possibly 3).

the getItem override returns a fragment and that what is displayed on each of the 5 tabs. Two fragments will utilize this activity's layout and I would like to somehow be able to make a conditional statement that will decipher which one is appropriate in which situation.

Here is my code:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SchResRanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public boolean isRanking;
public int daysPassed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sch_res_ran);

    //Toolbar schResRanBar = findViewById(R.id.theTopBar);
    //setSupportActionBar(schResRanBar);

    SectionPagerAdapter sectionPagerAdapter =
            new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(sectionPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    //tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_schresran_bar, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

void setPageTitle(){}

private class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

@Override
public int getCount() { return 6; }

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.day1);
        case 1:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.day2);
        case 2:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.day3);
        case 3:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.day4);
        case 4:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.day5);
        case 5:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.dayPlayoffs);
    }
    return null;
}
//this code depicts what I am trying to do but is way to clunky!
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       if (isRanking) {
        switch (position){
                case 0:
                     if (daysPassed >= 1) {
                    return new RankingsFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();
                case 1:
                       if (daysPassed >= 2) {
                    return new RankingsFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();
                case 2:
                     if (daysPassed >= 3) {
                    return new RankingsFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();                    case 3:
                case 4:
                     if (daysPassed >= 4) {
                    return new RankingsFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();
                case 5:
                     if (daysPassed >= 5) {
                    return new RankingsFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment(); 
                    } 
                  return null;

             if (isRanking == false) {
             case 0:
                     if (daysPassed >= 1) {
                    return new ScheduleFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();
                case 1:
                       if (daysPassed >= 2) {
                    return new ScheduleFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();
                case 2:
                     if (daysPassed >= 3) {
                    return new ScheduleFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();                    case 3:
                case 4:
                     if (daysPassed >= 4) {
                    return new ScheduleFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment();
                case 5:
                     if (daysPassed >= 5) {
                    return new ScheduleFragment();
                      } else {
                    return new NAFragment(); 
                    } 
        return null;
    }
    }
    }
```

This code depicts what I am trying to do but is way to clunky! can someone suggest a more efficient way to write this?

Assume that there is  a button called Rankings and a button called Schedule.
the onClick of both of these buttons both bring you to SchResRan activity ,but if schedule button is pressed the variable isRanking == false and each day there is different information dispayed. so if days passed == 0 no info is displayed on any page (all pages will be NA fragments) but if days passed == 1 the day 1 page will display day 1's info if days passed == 2 the day 1 and day 2 page will display the appropriate info so and so forth same for the rankings pages.

Comment: I mean...Yea I guess you're right...

Comment: I don't know why I was thinking of something unnecessarily more complex... thank you

Comment: hey @dubDeuce i change my reply...check it i remove whole switchcase its unusable in my new method fragment directly return ..and add position +1 inside method...you just directly need to use getItem(position) ..check it and tell its usefull ??

Comment: means you dont need to use switchcase and getFragment you see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create method for that

```
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       tempPosition=position+1;
      if (dayspassed>= tempPosition) 
          {
          if (isRanking) 
          {
          return new RankingsFragment();
          }else
          {
          return new ScheduleFragment();
          }
       } else 
       {
        return new NAFragment();
       }
     }
   }
```